# can i use dd to copy my dual boot HDD(350G) to smaller SSD(120GB) with only one of two OS from HDD

Tags: grub, dd, disk, mbr

I Have a dual boot machine (windows+ubuntu) with 350 GB HDD. I wish to clone only ubuntu to the 120GB SDD. How can I accomplish this.

PS: I have copied Linux partition(sda5) to SDD using "dd", What i need to do to preserve the geometry of a disk so that it can boot.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000f3d7c

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    718847    716800  350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 200712992 199994145 95.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       369358848 625139711 255780864  122G  6 FAT16
/dev/sda4       200714238 369358847 168644610 80.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       200714240 353449983 152735744 72.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       353452032 369358847  15906816  7.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 1):

Start over. Read this whole answer through at least once before you start, and make sure you understand it. If necessary copy it to an editor and fix up the assumed references to `/dev/sdaX` and `/dev/sdbX`. Really. You want to get these right because you have a very easy opportunity to break your existing installation completely and utterly. Really.

1. Partition the SSD.

   - You may need an UEFI boot partition.
   - You will need a partition that is at least the size of your `/dev/sda5` Linux partition.
   - You may want a Swap partition.
2. Copy the Linux partition you want to keep

   - Boot from a rescue disk
   - ASSUMING the target is `/dev/sdb2`, run `cat /dev/sda5 >/dev/sdb2`
   - Don't bother with `dd`. Using `cat` is no slower and usually far faster
3. Resize the target filesystem to fit the partition

   - ASSUMING the target is `/dev/sdb2` *and* your filesystem type is `ext3` or `ext4`, run `resize2fs /dev/sdb2`
4. Still using the rescue disk

   - ASSUMING the target is `/dev/sdb2`, run `chroot /dev/sdb2 /bin/bash`
   - Run the following commands, but be aware that your commands may vary depending on distribution

     ```
     grub-install /dev/sdb   # Second disk
     update-grub
     ```
5. Reboot and ensure that the new system can start up
6. Fix up the swap partition if you have one

   - ASSUMING your new swap is `/dev/sdb3`, run `mkswap /dev/sdb3`
   - Edit `/etc/fstab` to update (or comment out) the swap UUID definition
7. Remove your old disk and reboot

   - You may need to change the grub boot parameters temporarily to reference `hd0()` rather than `hd1()`. If so...
   - Run the following commands, or their equivalents, once more

     ```
     grub-install /dev/sda    # First disk, this time
     update-grub
     ```
8. Reboot once more

   - By this stage it should be booting smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answer. I have a dual-os setup.

1. Created a copy of ubuntu partitions on an external hard drive using gparted. This was done with live ubuntu USB
2. Deleted ubuntu partitions on the source disk
3. Clone copied Windows to the new SSD (target disk). Once done, a quick check to log into windows was successful.
4. Copied ubuntu partitions from the external hard drive to the new SSD. This was again done through live USB
5. Ran boot-repair tool to fix grub while on live USB

Upon reboot, was able to log into  both the OSes.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your contribution. If you refer to another answer in your post, please create an explicit link to it, because the display order of posts depends on user settings and is subject to change, so readers might later not understand which answer you are talking about.